# Unable to reach registry-1.docker.io from Kind cluster node on WSL2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, wsl-2, kind

I am setting up and airflow k8s cluster using kind deployment on a WSL2 setup. When I execute standard `helm install $RELEASE_NAME apache-airflow/airflow --namespace $NS` it fails. Further investigation shows that cluster worker node cannot connect to registry-1.docker.io.

Error log for one the image pull

```
Failed to pull image "redis:6-buster": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/redis:6-buster": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/redis:6-buster": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/redis/manifests/6-buster": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.19.0.1:53: no such host
```

I can access all other websites from this node e.g. google.com, yahoo.com merriam-webster.com etc. ; even docker.com works. This issue is very specific to registry-1.docker.io.

All the search and links seems to be around general internet connection issue.

**Current solution:**
If I manually change the `/etc/resolv.conf` on the kind worker node to point to the IP address from `/etc/resolv.conf` of the WSL2 Debian main IP address, then it works.

But, this is a dynamic cluster and node and I cannot do this every time. I am currently searching for a way as to how the make it a part of the cluster configuration. Some way that makes it work just by saying `kind create cluster` and one should be able to use `kubectl` or `helm` by default.

However, I am more interested in figuring out why this network setup fails specifically for registry-1.docker.io. Is there some configuration that can be done to avoid changing DNS to host IP or google DNS? As the current network configuration seems to work pretty much for the rest of the internet.

I have documented all the steps and investigation details including some of network configuration details on [github repositroy](https://github.com/arundeep78/airflow). If you need any further information to help solve the issue, please let me know. I will keep on updating the github documentation as I make progress.

**Setup:**

Windows 11 with WSL2 without any Docker desktop

WSL2 image : Debian bullseye (11) with docker engine on linux

Docker version : 20.10.2

Kind version : 0.11.1

Kind image: kindest/node:v1.20.7@sha256:cbeaf907fc78ac97ce7b625e4bf0de16e3ea725daf6b04f930bd14c
67c671ff9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if it is an answer or not. After  spending 2 days trying to find solution. I thought to change the node image version. On the [Kind release page](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/releases), it says 1.21 as the latest image for the kind version 0.11.1. I had problems with 1.21 to even start the cluster. 1.20 faced this strange DNS image. So went with 1.23. It all worked fine with thus image.

However, to my surprise, when I changed the cluster configuration back to 1.20, the DNS issue was gone. So, I do not what changed due to switch of of the image, but I cannot reproduce the issue again! Maybe it will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

I find that i have found the correct workaround for this bug: Switching IPTables to legacy mode has fixed this for me.

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1406#issuecomment-1183487816